# Javafx . How to get next Element non Focus Lost

Tags: java, javafx, focus

I have a focus-listener on a TextField and would like to know which will the next element that gains the focus. (And maybe change it under special circumstances)

Any Idea?

```
class Data extends TextField {
    public Data(int i) {
        focusedProperty().addListener((o, ov, nv) -> {
            if(!nv){               
              // Get Next Focusserd Item ...
            } 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: and then, what do you want to do with the next? Listen to changes in scene.focusOwner - that's when the next will be focused. BTW unrelated, _don't_ subclass controls (nor any other classes) if you can achieve your goal by configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the value of the `focusOwner` property from the scene.

```
Node focusOwner = getScene().getFocusOwner();
```

`requestFocus` can be used to get the focus to some other node, e.g.

```
if (focusOwner != otherNode) {
    thirdNode.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: hmm ... don't think that's what the OP wants - which I think is something like focusOwner.focusNext (not available because the focusTraversal didn't make it into public scope) .. or maybe not, re-reading the question ;)